# How to pass information from one view (dockable) to another?

Tags: java, javafx, drombler-fx

I am facing a design problem. If I have (for example) on the left dockable view a list view that contains some pojo's, how do I notify the center dockable which one is selected? I am trying to implement some kind of Master-Detail-View where the user selects one item and then can configure it in the center area and the right area. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is a bit too broad. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx for techniques for sharing data among multiple controllers/

Comment: The problem is that this isn't fairly easy with the dromblerfx framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to design your application.

If you want to create a separate Editor for each pojo then you can have a look at the LeftTestPane provided by the [drombler fx archetype](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#_create_the_application) for a sample.

```
@FXML
private void onNewSampleAction(ActionEvent event) {
    sampleCounter++;
    Sample sample = new Sample("Sample " + sampleCounter);
    SampleEditorPane sampleEditorPane = new SampleEditorPane(sample);
    Dockables.inject(sampleEditorPane);
    Dockables.open(sampleEditorPane);
}
```

There is currently no API for selecting an already opened editor, but please note that editors are currently being improved with the work done for issue [#111](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues/111).

If you want a single detail view then you can use the [Context Framework](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/context-framework.html#contextFramework), which allows components such as Dockables and Actions to communicate in a loosly coupled way.

The ListView should implement [LocalContextProvider](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/context/LocalContextProvider.html) and keep the selected pojo in its local [Context](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/context/Context.html).

```
@ViewDocking(...)
public class ListView extends SomeNode implements LocalContextProvider {

    private final SimpleContextContent contextContent = new SimpleContextContent();
    private final SimpleContext context = new SimpleContext(contextContent);
    private MyPojo currentSelection;

    ...

    @Override
    public Context getLocalContext() {
        return context;
    }

    ...

    if (currentSelection != null){
        contextContent.remove(currentSelection);
    }
    currentSelection = <current selection>
    if (currentSelection != null){
        contextContent.add(currentSelection);
    }
    ...
}
```

In this case, the DetailsView should be registered as a view (singleton), too, and implement [LocalContextProvider](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/context/LocalContextProvider.html) as well as [ActiveContextSensitive](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/context/ActiveContextSensitive.html):

```
@ViewDocking(...)
public class DetailsPane extends SomeNode implements ActiveContextSensitive, LocalContextProvider {

    private final SimpleContextContent contextContent = new SimpleContextContent();
    private final SimpleContext context = new SimpleContext(contextContent);
    private Context activeContext;
    private MyPojo myPojo;

    ...

    @Override
    public Context getLocalContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setActiveContext(Context activeContext) {
        this.activeContext = activeContext;
        this.activeContext.addContextListener(MyPojo.class, (ContextEvent event) -> contextChanged());
        contextChanged();
    }

    private void contextChanged() {
        MyPojo newMyPojo = activeContext.find(MyPojo.class);
        if ((myPojo == null && newMyPojo != null) || (myPojo null && !sample.equals(newMyPojo))) {
            if (myPojo != null) {
                unregister();
            }
            myPojo = newMyPojo;
            if (myPojo != null) {
                register();
            }
        }
    }

    private void unregister() {
        contextContent.remove(myPojo);

        //reset DetailsView
    }

    private void register() {
        // configure DetailsView

        contextContent.add(myPojo);
    }
...
}
```

Have a look at the RightTestPane provided by the [drombler fx archetype](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#_create_the_application) for a sample.